# Material Angular Input/MatFormField does not load correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

My input is not being displayed correctly (an input field should exist to the left of the button):

[image]

If I give the form a background color, I can see that the input is actually rendered, but with a white color:

[image]

How can I debug this?

HTML:

```html
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="keywordForm" (ngSubmit)="addKeyword()">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Keywords</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        formControlName="keyword"
        placeholder="Ex: Bananas"
    /></mat-form-field>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!keywordForm.valid">
      Add
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is how I initialize the form:

```js
keywordForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  keyword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
});
```

And I think I've imported the necessary Modules:

```js
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

Comment: When you say you imported modules, are you saying you imported them in app.module.ts and in imports array?

Comment: Yup, they are correctly imported in the respective submodule. The submodule is then imported in the app.module.ts. Does the Material modules need to be imported in both the submodule and the main module?